# Big-O algorithmic analysis

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I would say it's not a homework problem. It's just a tutorial resource online to learn the dynamic programming concepts from USACO website.
In the resource, a problem was given as follows.

Question:
    A sequcen of as many as 10000 integers, ( 0 < integer < 100,000), what is the maximum decreasing subsequence?

The decent recursive approach was given

```
 1 #include <stdio.h>      
 2  long n, sequence[10000];
 3  main () {
 4       FILE *in, *out;                     
 5       int i;                             
 6       in = fopen ("input.txt", "r");     
 7       out = fopen ("output.txt", "w");   
 8       fscanf(in, "%ld", &n);             
 9       for (i = 0; i < n; i++) fscanf(in, "%ld", &sequence[i]);
10       fprintf (out, "%d\n", check (0, 0, 99999));
11       exit (0);
12  }


13  check (start, nmatches, smallest) {
14      int better, i, best=nmatches;
15      for (i = start; i < n; i++) {
16          if (sequence[i] < smallest) {
17              better = check (i, nmatches+1, sequence[i]);
18              if (better > best) best = better;
19          }
20      }
21      return best;
22  }
```

Guys, I am not good at the algorithmic analysis. Would you please tell me what's the Big-O notation to this recursive enumeration solution in worst case as tight as possible.  My personal thought would be O(N^N), but I have no confidence. Because the runtime is still acceptable under N <= 100. There must be something wrong. Please help me. Thank you.

In the USACO website, it gives the dynamic programming approach in O(n^2) as follows.

```cpp
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2  #define MAXN 10000
 3  main () {
 4      long num[MAXN], bestsofar[MAXN];
 5      FILE *in, *out;
 6      long n, i, j, longest = 0;
 7      in = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
 8      out = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
 9      fscanf(in, "%ld", &n);
10      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) fscanf(in, "%ld", &num[i]);
11      bestsofar[n-1] = 1;
12      for (i = n-1-1; i >= 0; i--) {
13          bestsofar[i] = 1;
14          for (j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
15              if (num[j] < num[i] && bestsofar[j] >= bestsofar[i])  {
16                  bestsofar[i] = bestsofar[j] + 1;
17                  if (bestsofar[i] > longest) longest = bestsofar[i];
18              }
19          }
20      }
21      fprintf(out, "bestsofar is %d\n", longest);
22      exit(0);
23  }
```

Comment: Edit first your post to say why you think it is `O(N^N)`. did you really meant N at the power of N??

Comment: Your solution works in `O(2^N)` in the worst case (decreasing sequence). Therefore it should work slow with `N = 30` (approximately `10^9` calls of check). Are you sure you use the worst test case?

Comment: When you start looking for an O(nlogn) solution, I recommend you look at the algorithm on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms). It uses only arrays and a binary searching.

Answer (score 3):

Just look at with what kind of parameters you call the function. The first determines the third (which btw means you needed have the third parameter). The first ranges between 0 and n. The second one is smaller than the first. This means that you have at most n^2 different calls to the function.

Now comes the question how many times you call the function with the same parameters. And the answer is simple: you actually generate every single decreasing subsequece. This means that for the sequence N, N-1, N-2, ... you will generate 2^N sequences. Pretty poor, right (if you want experiment with the sequence I have given you)?

However if you use the memoization technique you should have already read about, you can improve the complexity to N^3 (at most n operations in every call to the function, the different calls are N^2 and memoization allows you to pay only once for a different call).

Comment: That answer is right; however, it should be noted you can solve it in `O(n log n)`.

Comment: True of course - you need to use dynamic RMQ. However it is a bit early for you to think (I mean @user1215751) of this solution.

Comment: With memoization it's actually `O(n²)`. You only need one parameter, the start index: `check(start)` returns the length of the longest decreasing subsequence starting at `start`. Then there are only `n` different states, so the maximum number of calls is `n`.

Comment: @tom - not entirely - you can not do only with the start (you will need to decide whether you can include the currently processed item cna increase the length of the sequence too).

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I believe this works:
`int check(int start) { int best = 1; for (int i = start + 1; i < n; i++) { if (sequence[i] < sequence[start]) { best = max(best, check(i) + 1); } } return best; }`
(sorry about the lack of newlines)

Comment: @tom ah, of course, you are right. This is usually the case - when you start coding those more sophisticated solutions - you always shoot flies with bazooka.

Comment: @tom, thank you. Btw, I still not very clear why is it O(n^2) in the memorization procedure. Is it becuase 1) there are only n states ( the state here means the number of LDS ? )  2) In each state, there are at most n function calls. Therefore, combining 1) & 2) gives  O(n^2) complexity?

Comment: @Edward Sort of. With memoization (aka caching), calling the function a second time with the same set of parameters is O(1). Only the first time is slow. The size of the cache (and the total number of first-time calls) is equal to the number of different combinations (states) the parameters can have. In this case, there is just one parameter (`start`) which must be between 0 and n - 1, so the size of the cache and the total number of slow O(n) calls is n.